# Meta Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Some discussions don't belong even on meta, e.g. when it's pure noise.

But sometimes we want to make some noise amongst ourselves, don't we? At least I know I do. I've only been on Stack Overflow for a few months, but I already felt like I've started to develop some connections to other users, and just want to... chat?

So where can we do this? Is there an IRC/Google wave channel/whatever where SO users hang out where we can just ask, "How's everybody doing today?"

Comment: How ironic would it be if this question gets closed for "noise, pointless"...

Comment: All comments on this meta-*MetaSO* question are meta-meta-*MetaSO*.  Any response or statement about this comment (including this statement itself) is meta-meta-meta-*MetaSO*.  The parenthetical statement in the last sentence was meta-meta-meta-meta-*MetaSO*, and as would be a response regarding *the previous sentence alone*.  Okay, I'm done now.

Comment: Let's have a devnull.stackoverflow.com

Comment: This problem could become catastrophically recursive.

Comment: @TimPost, the _de facto_ maximum URL length is [2083 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url/417184#417184), so the recursion would end at `[meta^411].stackoverflow.com`. At that point... I guess the Internet's stack would overflow?

Answer (score 16):

Since this question was asked, a chat system was implemented. It's currently split into three areas:

- Stack Overflow (https://chat.stackoverflow.com);
- Meta Stack Exchange (http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com); and
- all other sites (https://chat.stackexchange.com; access a specific site's chatrooms directly through `http://chat.[parent site name].com`).

Comment: And now, MSE chat.

Answer (score 5):

If we go with meta.meta.stackoverflow.com, then next we will wonder what is the deepest possible meta-level. This is kind of insane. ;-) Reminds me of [Inception](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/) (movie).

BTW, isn't discussion about "meta.meta." topic for "meta.meta.meta." ? ;-P

Comment: The deepest possible meta-level contains 411 metas; see my comment under the question.

Comment: @PopularDemand: unless we figure out some compressed form ;-P