# Meta Stack Overflow needs a Meta Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, per-site-meta

Meta Stack Overflow has gotten a bit (well, not *just* a bit) out of hand, what with all of the ponies, the perfect freehand circle obsessions, the parakeets, the haikus, the ponies, the circle and the haikus, and that's only half of the problem.

I'm not suggesting anything at all similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54973/meta-meta-stackoverflow), since I seriously want to be able to talk about how weird Meta Stack Overflow really is.

My only hope is that MMSO will not get as screwy as MSO is right now, since then we'd be on our way to an infinite (or rather, 411 time) recursion, unless we can define a base case of some sort.

Any ideas?
And please no ponies.

Comment: Off topic. Belongs on MMSO.

Comment: The memes tailed off a long time ago.  You're the reading history of Meta, apparently.

Comment: @BilltheLizard is right, memes are SO 6 to 8 weeks ago!

Answer (score 3):

And when do you stop? Besides, as it has been noted, Meta Stack Overflow is special in that it's the Meta of all Metas - which, when you think about it, includes itself. So any questions about Meta Stack Overflow belong on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly enough, Meta-StackOverflow doesn't actually say it discusses itself.

Comment: @Filipq: Not explicitly on the site description, but if you read the many questions about why reputation from other websites carries over to the Meta versions but not on Stack Overflow/Meta Stack Overflow, moderators note this.

Comment: "The set of all sets which include themselves ...."

Comment: @TRiG But far more interesting is the set of all sets which exclude themselves...