# Meta on Meta. Missing line in the Meta Faq

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, meta, faq-update-request, meta-faq

The Meta FAQ starts with:

```
If your question is about:

Stack Overflow  
Stack Exchange  
Stack Overflow Careers  
Promotions & Advertising  
Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the 
   core Stack Exchange engine that powers  all Stack Exchange websites

... it is welcome here.
```

So, according to the rules, the questions about *Meta Stackoverflow* itself couldn't be asked on *Meta Stackoverflow*. Because it is not any one of the list. Does Meta^2 already exist? Or better it would be to add *Meta Stackoverflow* itself into its own list?

It is not the double of [Meta Meta Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54973/meta-meta-stackoverflow), I am not talking on the theme " just want to... chat?". 
I understand that really all practic questions about Meta are to be put on Meta and are put on MetaHere is even a tag for it. But the FAQ should be repaired to fit the practice, IMHO. The recursion should be closed somewhere.

Comment: by your definition this question doesn't belong here ;)

Comment: "Stack Exchange" can encompass MSO if we want to get persnickety about it. I don't think this is an actual, real issue.

Comment: I think it would do to just add Meta Stack Overflow as a list item in the list you refer to.

Comment: @KevinVermeer This is about the MSO faq rather than about meta MSO and, thus, not a duplicate of those questions.

Comment: @KevinVermeer there the question is:  "I would assume that the same rules apply in that you cannot talk about Meta on Meta." So, mine is the opposite of that one. I only ask to keep the FAQ up to the contemporary practice.

Comment: @N.N. That is what I am asking for.

Comment: @KevinVermeer In that list "Stack Exchange" may be interpreted as the Stack Exchange engine and not the whole set of Stack Exchange sites. For clarity I think it would be best to add Meta Stack Overflow to the list. By your argument, that Meta Stack Overflow does not have to be included in the list, the list could be reduced to Stack Exchange only. But, clearly, that is confusing.

Comment: @Madmartigan the server that speaks about rules, should keep the rules best of all.

Comment: @Gangnus You might want to modify your title and question to focus on that you are after an update of the faq. Russell's paradox is not that relevant for the issue. The main thing is that to avoid confusion "Meta Stack Overflow" should be added to the list of allowed topics in the faq.

Comment: I know, that it only looks as the Russel paradox. The title was meant as a partly joke. But some people don't like them.

Comment: @KevinVermeer Thank you for removing that "bunch of mathematicians and programmists"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The recursion is closed here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64)

Answer (score 0):

With due respect to Jarrod Dixon, [the recursion is closed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121888).